# How to change tags and content onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a quiz site where users can create their own quiz. Due to javascript function problems when tags and classes are named the same in different sections of the DOM, I have had to change element tag names and class names to prevent errors.

Please see an extract of my code below and my problem. I have many question options but here is an example:

HTML Main Quiz Page:

```
<ul id = "question1" class = "questions">What colour is my hair?
    <li>Brown</li>
    <li class = "correct">Blonde</li>
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Black</li>
</ul>
```

HTML Create Quiz Page:

```
<p id = "questionOption1" class = "questionChoice">What Superpower would I have?
    <span class = "correctAnswer">Fly</span>
    <span>Invisibility</span>
    <span>Telekenisis</span>
    <span>Super Strength</span>
</p>
Now pick your correct answer & click Save
<button class="Save">Save</button>
```

What I am trying to do is replace the question1 content with the questionOption1 content and change the class "correctAnswer" to "correct" so when you click the Save button question1 on the main quiz page becomes this:

HTML:

```
<ul id = "question1" class = "questions">What Superpower would I have?
    <li class = "correct">Fly</li>
    <li>Invisibility</li>
    <li>Telekenisis</li>
    <li>Super Strength</li>
</ul>
```

I have all my javascript working and keeping track of the score for the amount of questions the user gets right. All I really need to do now is change the elements and classes of the questionOptions block of code and insert it into the question1 block of code on the main quiz page, but I just do not know how to actually change the tag names and classes when Save is clicked.

This is all in one html file separated by sections using hide() show() methods.

Any help would be most appreciated...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to replace the html of question 1 with the html of questionOption1, you can do something like

```
$( ".Save" ).click(function() {
    var questionOptionHtml = $('#questionOption1').html();
    $('#question1').html(questionOptionHtml);
});
```

I'll confess that the .Save click worries me. If you only have 1 question on the page, I'd suggest have the button be

```
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

and then change the .click method to be

```
$( ".Save" ).click(function() {
    var questionOptionHtml = $('#questionOption1').html();
    $('#question1').html(questionOptionHtml);
});
```

**If you have multiple questions and saves on more than 1 page**, I would either make this save buttons have ids, have each question block have a surrounding class to have a click event associated with it, or make it more dynamic. I'd highly recommend the latter even if it would be slightly more complicated, it would certainly be less maintenance in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Jared. I only have one html page. There are 10 questions in the main quiz page and there are 20 questionOptions the user can choose from. Each questionOption block of code is the same as my example. So as the user clicks Save for each questionOption it changes the html content for each question...I assume if the Save button has an ID attr and not a Class attr it would be #Save and not .Save? As ID's should be unique. I am hoping to have one function to achieve this and not 10 different functions for each individual questionOption.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like in Jared Drake's answer.

But I think it would be easier to use a templating engine like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to simplify the replacing of your markup.

With templating you can store your questions in an object and re-render them on changes.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/kac2xhp4/).

```js
var $answerOptions = $('.createQuestion span'),
 data = {
     questions: [{
            no: 1,
            question: 'What colour is my hair?',
            answers: [
                {correct:false, text: 'Brown'},
                {correct:true, text: 'Blonde'},
                {correct:false, text: 'Red'},
                {correct:false, text: 'Black'}
            ]
        }]
    };

// compile handlebars
function renderQuestions() {
    var source = $("#appTemplate").html();
    //console.log(source);
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    $('#questionContainer').html(template(data));
}

renderQuestions(); // initial render
//console.log($answerOptions);

// --------------------- question functions --------------------
$(document).on('click', '#questionContainer li', function() {
 var answer = $(this).hasClass('correct');
    
    // remove previous choices
    $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('correctChoice incorrectChoice');
 
    //console.log(answer);
    $(this).addClass(answer ? 'correctChoice': 'incorrectChoice');
});


//---------------------- creation function ------------------
// select answer option click handler
$('.createQuestion span').click(function(e) {
 var $answerOptions = $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('span');
    
    $answerOptions.removeClass('correctAnswer');
    $(e.target).closest($('span')).addClass('correctAnswer');
    //console.log($answerOptions);
    
});

$('.createQuestion .add').click(function(e) {
 var $answerOptions = $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('span'),
     newQuestion = {
         no: data.questions.length,
            question: $('.questionChoice').clone().children().remove().end().text(), // works but a markup change would be better here
            answers: []
        };
 $answerOptions.each(function(index, answer) {
      newQuestion.answers.push({
            correct: $(answer).hasClass('correctAnswer'),
            text: $(answer).text()
        });
    });
    
    data.questions.push(newQuestion);
    renderQuestions();
    //console.log(newQuestion);
});
```

```css
.createQustion, span {
    display: block;
}

.correctAnswer {
    background-color: green;
}

.correctChoice {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.incorrectChoice {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="appTemplate">
 {{#each questions}}
     {{this.question}}
        <ul class="questions" id={{this.no}}>
            {{#each answers}}
                {{#if this.correct}}
                 <li class='correct'>{{this.text}}</li>
                {{else}}
                 <li>{{this.text}}</li>
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/each}}
</script>
<div id="app">
    <div id="questionContainer">
    </div>
    <div class="createQuestion">
        <h2>
        Enter new question:
        </h2>
        <p id="questionOption1" class="questionChoice">What Superpower would I have?
        <span class="correctAnswer">Fly</span>
        <span>Invisibility</span>
        <span>Telekenisis</span>
        <span>Super Strength</span>
        </p>
        Now pick your correct answer & click Save
        <button class="add">Add question</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @AWolf. I ran your code and it added the question below the original. What I really want to do is replace the question and change the tag names from <p> to <ul> and <span> to <li> and change the class "correctAnswer" to "correct"...I was thinking something like this: if $(span).hasClass("correctAnswer"); $(span).removeClass("correctAnswer"); $(this).addClass("correct"); but I do not know how to change the elements tag names.

Comment: I think you only need to take my code and add a form inside of `createQuestion` div. Then you have a form for creating new questions. How should your quiz creation work? You have 10 questions and at each you'd like to have a way to edit that question, right? And the answers are all predefined, so the user can select from a set of answer options for that question?